# Not able to create a NiFi custom processor project in IntelliJ IDEA using maven archetype

Tags: intellij-idea, maven-3, apache-nifi, maven-archetype

I'm on IntelliJ IDEA v `2021.1` and trying to create a "Apache NiFi custom processor project" by using the archetype located [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.nifi/nifi-processor-bundle-archetype/1.13.2)

Since the archetype is not available by default in IDEA, I added it by using "Add Archetype" button using following parameters:

```
GroupId:    org.apache.nifi
ArtifactId: nifi-processor-bundle-archetype
Version:    1.13.2
```

But in the "New Module" creation window, during the first attempt, i left the property "archetypeRepository" as blank and second time, gave it as "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2"

But both times, it threw an error

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-archetype-plugin:3.2.0:generate (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: The desired archetype does not exist (org.apache.nifi:nifi-maven-archetypes:1.13.2)
```

I also get following in the Logs:

```
[INFO] Generating project in Batch mode
[WARNING] Archetype not found in any catalog. Falling back to central repository.
[WARNING] Add a repository with id 'archetype' in your settings.xml if archetype's repository is elsewhere.
```

Interestingly, I also have standalone Maven installed in the system, and when I try to create the same project using command line, it works fine.

Both the standalone and embedded Maven (in IDEA) is v `3.6.3`

Why is the project creation from inside IDEA not working ?

Comment: Try adding this plugin to IntelliJ IDEA and check whether it's working - https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7965-maven-archetype-catalogs

Comment: @VikramsinhShinde already tried it. I'm not sure what URL to give in its "Add Archetype Catalog URL", i tried with "https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/nifi/nifi-processor-bundle-archetype/1.13.2/" , but it says, URL does not point to valid archetype catalog.